# How to update row if exist and meet more than one condition and insert it otherwise in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to perform the below code which I have found it in a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312432/best-practice-to-update-a-row-if-exists-otherwise-insert)

```
UPDATE MyGuests 
SET lastname = 'Doe' 
WHERE id = 2

IF ROW_COUNT() = 0
   INSERT INTO MyGuests (lastname, id) 
   VALUES ('Doe', 2)
```

The problem is that I need to do the same thing but with the SQL Server query.
My main thought here is that if the new read has the same `BoxNo` and the same `SSCC` and the same `StyleBarcode`, then the value in `Qty` column will be updated by +1. Otherwise, it'll make a new insert.

I'm thinking to make something like the following code:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET Qty = Qty + 1 
WHERE BoxNo = 1 
  AND SSCC = 15210049000887900 
  AND StyleBarcode = 5210132138457

IF ROW_COUNT() = 0
   INSERT INTO MyTable (SSCC, StyleBarcode, Qty) 
   VALUES (15210049000887900, 5210132138457, 1)
```

But I couldn't make it because I don't have something like the `ROW_COUNT()` in SQL Server.

Or I don't know if you can make have it done in another way?

Thanks in advance.

My table:

[image: MyTestTabel]

Comment: TSQL says [`@@RowCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). And please don't post pictures of data unless you would like an artistic impression of a query as an answer.

Comment: @HABO Noted with thanks, I’ll not do it in future, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server implements [the `merge` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which seems relevant for your use case.

This statement lets you `insert` or `update` from one table into a given table , according to well-defined predicates.

For your question, that would be:

```
merge mytable as t
using (values (15210049000887900,5210132138457,1)) as s(sscc, styleBarcode, qty)
on (t.sscc = s.sscc and t.styleBarcode = s.styleBarcode)
when matched then 
    update set t.qty = t.qty + 1  -- or t.qty = t.qty + s.qty?
when not matched then 
    insert(sscc,styleBarcode,qty) values(s.sscc, s.styleBarcode, s.qty)
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me. I hope I would be successful in combining it in my C# code using parameters instead of `15210049000887900,5210132138457,1` . can I do that? would you please kindly explain a little bit how this code works? I'm kind of new on the MERGE statement. thanks again